# Django, add field from a join in my QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models

- I have a model Exec with a FK User (the django's one)
- I have a model Profil with a FK User (the django's one)

I have a QuerySet of Exec and I want to get a field from Profil in it by "joining" with Profil by the FK. How can i do that?

The goal is to have something like *exec.profil_info* or *exec.profil.info*

Comment: Try: `Exec.objects.all().filter(user__profil__somefield = "somevalue")`

Comment: I do not want to filter, I want to add some user information from its profil in my Exec list

Comment: What is the "somevalue"?

Comment: ah, sorry, my mistake, edited: `.annotate(some_name = Value('user__profil__somefield'))`

Comment: Mmmm user__profil means field profil of user. But as I said, it is profil which has a user field

Comment: Yes, `user` - this is a field in `Exec` model, `profil` - this is a reverse ForeignKey field relation in `User <- Profil` model, - u have to enable it in ForeignKey field parameters `(related_name = 'profil')`, `somefield` - is a field in `Profil` model. U didn't show your models, so I have theoretically explain this.

Comment: Did u get that?

Comment: I'll test tomorrow. Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
Exec.objects.all().select_related('user__user_profile')
```

but it only works if in Profil model there is a field:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True, related_name='user_profile')
```

With a FK it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this 'join'  by using OuterRef and Subquery https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions.

For your example

```
profiles = Profil.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'))
subquery  = Subquery(profiles.values('your_field_here')[:1])
execs = Exec.objects.annotate(anything=subquery)
```

This will give you the first matching row from `Profil` table (you can control ordering by adding order_by to profiles QuerySet).